# how to know if a character is a carriage return?

Tags: bash

**Problem :**

I have always been able while looping through characters to identify the char I want. However, now that I want to identify a carriage return, my way of doing things doesn't seem to work :

```
function removeCarriageReturn()
{
  word=""

  while IFS= read -r -n1 char ; do
    if [ "${char}" != "\r" ] ; then
      word="${word}${char}"
    fi
  done <<<"$1"

  printf '%s\n' "$word"
}
```

**Result :**

For a reason I don't know, it adds a "$" in front of the carriage return, why?
Here is the result (from Jenkins) :

*When char analysed is for example 8*

```
++ '[' 8 '!=' '\r' ']'
```

*When char analysed is \r*

```
++ '[' $'\r' '!=' '\r' ']'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sidestepping your actual question, the easiest way to remove any carriage returns from a value is

```
value=${value//$'\r'}
```

(which also demonstrates that your `if` statement would read

```
if [ "$char" != $'\r' ]; then.
```

Note that this is the same syntax that `-x` is using to display the carriage return.)

Comment: This only removes from the end. The OPs loop removes anywhere.

Comment: will mark it as answer, thanks! Your first option, does it remove all instances?

Comment: It does. `${value/$'\r'}` would only remove the first instance; doubling the `/` removes *all* instances.

Answer (score 5):

`$''` quoting is [ANSI-C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) and it interprets some escape sequences.

Nothing is being *added* there that's just `set -x` showing you what is *actually* happening. You don't have the two-character string `"\r"` you have a literal `\r` and that's what `$'\r'` is.

This fact (and the `set -x` output) also tell you how to match the character you are looking for. Use `$'\r'`.